# Ionic progress bar still appears as a spinner

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am implementing loading as shown below. When I run the application on my iOS, the loading still shows as a spinner instead of a progress bar. Why is this happening in my app?

**List.ts**

```js
async presentLoadingDefault() {
    this.loading =  await this.loadCtrl.create({
        content: '<ion-progress-bar value="0.5"></ion-progress-bar>'
    });

    await this.loading.present();

}

async dismissLoader()
{
    await this.loading.dismiss();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid **ionic 3** doesn't support `ion-progress-bar` component.

It is formally supported by **ionic 4**. Refer [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/progress-bar).

In order to implement `progress-bar` in **ionic 3**, please follow this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-progressbar-muthu-ewl6ag) tutorial.

**progress-bar.html**

```html
<div class="progress-outer">
  <div class="progress-inner" [style.width]="progress + '%'">
    {{progress}}%
  </div>
</div>
```